# If a language is context free, then its complement is decidable

Tags: formal-languages, computability, context-free, closure-properties

I am having a bit of trouble figuring this out. If L is context-free then we know it is decidable. The class of decidable languages is closed under complement thus, $L$ $\cap$ $L^{c}$, therefore $L^{c}$ is decidable.

Does this make any sense?

Comment: Eliminate the "thus $L\cap L^c$" portion; it adds nothing to your proof.

Answer (score 1):

If $L$ is context free, it is decidable. Thus so is it's complement (to see if $\sigma \in L^c$, check if it is in $L$ and answer the opposite).

$L \cap L^c = \varnothing$, which is certainly decidable (just say no).

Your question is *seriously* confused...

Comment: From my understanding the problems tells me that L is context free. Since the problem does not tell me that its complement is decidable I show $L \cap L^{c}$ which I know equals the empty string and is decidable so I conclude that $L \cap L^{c}$ which shows $L^{c}$ is decidable.